# How to create CSV file using CSV gem in ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, csv

I am new to ruby 1.9.2. How to generate CSV file in a single ruby script file?

Here, I wrote a ruby script,

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pg'
require 'active_record'
require 'csv'

class AttachEmail

def generate_csv
begin
filename = "csvout.csv"
users = User.all
users.each do |u|
    products = Product.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_id=?",u.id])
    CSV.open(filename, 'w') do |csv|
    # header row
user_name = u.name
      csv << ['Report']
      csv << ['Name','Product', 'Item Count']
      products.each do |product|
      csv << [user_name, product.title,product.count]
      end
end
end
rescue Exception => e
  puts e
end
end
generate= AttachEmail.new
generate.generate_csv
```

When i run this script.it will produce output like below,

```
         A                    B        C

0      Report
1      Name,Product,Item    Count
2      user1,PD123,10,990
```

But I need output like, separate column, Please can you kind me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What part of the documentation is giving you difficulty? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Hi @mu, I have tried, Please look at edited question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to swap loops if you are trying to put all the user data in the same file, and not overwrite it for every user:

```
CSV.open(filename, 'w') do |csv|
  users.each do |u|
    products = Product.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_id=?",u.id])
```

Next, fix your Excel (I suspect the output is taken from it, right?) to use comma as a separator, not a "space or comma".

Come back with the file contents attached and an example of CSV file which works for you if it still doesn't work.